# call paintComponet agian

Tags: java, swing

I make a ImagePanel class that get a ImageIcon object and draw it show panel.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Graphics;

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private ImageIcon img;

    public ImagePanel(ImageIcon img) {
        this.setImage(img);
    }

    public void setImage(ImageIcon img){
        this.img = img;

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(img instanceof ImageIcon)
            g.drawImage(img.getImage(), 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
    }
}
```

but the problem is when I change the img, it don't show it on panel till I change frame size. how can I update it?

EDIT: repaint() does not clean last img on panel.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would simply need to call `repaint` within the `setImage` method.

You should be calling `super.paintComponent` in order to prevent any possibility of introducing paint artifacts into your rendering process.

You should should consider overriding `getPreferredSize` in order to ensure that the component will be laid out properly under most layout managers.  This should reflect the size of the `img`.

Unless you have some reason to do otherwise, you could just get away with using `JLabel`

Comment: I cant use JLabel because I need add some object to it and I need image size be some az Panel size. and I have use repaint() before but it don't delete last img.

Comment: *"You should be calling `super.paintComponent` in order to prevent any possibility of introducing paint artifacts into your rendering process."*  +1.  From the sounds of it, that is the exact cause of this problem.

Comment: _I don't get it. where should I add super.paintComponent() and what parameter should I use for It?_ You can override a method but don't know how to call its super? Time for going back to the introductory chapters of a decent tutorial on java :-)